# Flatten a set of pairs in Rust

Tags: rust, set, flatten

I am working with sets of pairs of integers in Rust using `HashSet<(usize, usize)>`, and my goal is to compute a set `HashSet<usize>` which contain all nodes appearing in those pairs. Essentially, this is a `flatten` operation.

Let's suppose variable `set: HashSet<(usize, usize)>` contains the initial set of pairs. My first attempt to compute the flattened version was:

```rust
let res: HashSet<usize> = set.iter().flatten().collect()
```

however I encounter the error: "`&(usize, usize)` is not an iterator the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `&(usize, usize)` required for `&(usize, usize)` to implement `IntoIterator`. Required by a bound in `flatten`."

I thought the issue was that the iterator was over references so I also tried using `into_iter` instead, but I get the same error message, this time saying "`(usize, usize)` is not an iterator..."

I do have a piece of code that works fine using a `for` loop and the `push` operation, but I would like to do it in a more functional way with `flatten`.

Comment: It might be worth considering making the first set `HashSet<[usize;2]>` instead at wich point your call to `flatten()` just works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply convert the tuple to an array, which is iterable:

```rust
let res: HashSet<usize> = set.iter().flat_map(|&(a, b)| [a, b]).collect();
```